# How to install PgBouncer on Windows 7 (x64)

Tags: postgresql, gnu-make, libevent, pgbouncer

I am attempting to install PgBouncer on my computer with no success.  In the  [installation page](https://pgbouncer.github.io/install.html), im told that PgBouncer has two dependencies [GNU Make 3.81+](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) and [libevent 2.0](http://libevent.org/).  Never having used or heard of these two software before, Im completely lost.

I have read a little on both but have yet to find or fully understand what they actually do and how they will help me set up PgBouncer.  From what I've read, PgBouncer does not come compiled for windows and I need the other two to compile it.  I have searched for tutorials online but it seems that im falling into a black hole of misunderstanding.

Im looking for a simple explanation on how to install PgBouncer or how these software work with one another. Thanks.

Comment: There are windows binaries available: http://winpg.jp/~saito/pgbouncer/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - how safe are these

Comment: As far as I know they are compiled by the author himself

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name ill take a look.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name -  have you ran any of these.  I downloaded the 1.5.5 x64 & x32 version, created a pgbouncer.ini and user file, but everytime a run the command `pgbouncer pgbouncer.ini` on cmd prompt not happens. Any suggestions

Comment: @JoseRodrigues have you figured it out? I'm about to try the same thing

Comment: @chester89 I believe I ended up using the window binaries that a_horse_with_no_name suggested.

Comment: I can confirm those are valid binaries. Windows service wasn't working for some reason, I ended up running a command line

Comment: I don't know if it's just for me or anyone else as well, but http://winpg.jp/~saito/pgbouncer/ seems to be offline. I have launched a Github pages page with the binaries: https://sepppenner.github.io/PgBouncerWinBinaries/. I tried to compile them by myself, but did not yet succeed...

Comment: @FranzHuber23 I posted an answer that should help you out. Let me know if it does

Answer (score 1):

If anyone now searches the binaries because http://winpg.jp/~saito/pgbouncer is offline now, check out my page under https://sepppenner.github.io/PgBouncerWinBinaries/. I have all the binaries from the Saito page <s>but didn't yet succeed to build the project on my own. If anyone has ideas, don't hesitate to contact me here or on Github :)</s>

**EDIT:** I'm now able to build pgbouncer for windows just having some issues with the pandoc thing (Follow https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/442). I will provide binaries soon. The instructions are already online under the page listed above :)

Answer (score 1):

> Im looking for a simple explanation on how to install PgBouncer

A little late, but if you use the EDB installer for PostgreSQL, as linked on postgresql.org (https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/), you can install Stack Builder. From inside Stack Builder, PgBouncer can be installed (EDB build).

Unfortunately, it's not the latest version. Now, PgBouncer 1.17.0 is available and Stack Builder provides 1.16.1.

Personally, I don't understand why the PgBouncer project doesn't just offer a Windows build. So everybody would be able to get the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

I have not messed with pgbouncer in years but have had multiple comments on what I did to solve my problem.

In the link bellow is the pgbouncer build I last used on my project.  From what I remember, all you would need to do is replace the users in the config/user.txt with yours and go into config/pgbouncer.ini and change the configuration to work with your set up. To start it, just run the run.bat file or `pgbouncer.exe config/pgbouncer.ini`in the cmd prompt.  You want to download everything in the folder.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1f8MjdQCq-ryQBiJ85d4hABASFfR_6fA2

Comment: Well, thank you for this, but I have the binaries as well (Published under https://sepppenner.github.io/PgBouncerWinBinaries as stated above). The problem was that I don't seem to get it work to build PgBouncer from code...